# Is there a word that means English-Language-Centric?

Tags: word-usage, connotation, speech, general-vs-specific

There was an argument about how someone spelled "Revolution" and they said "No, I did not write it incorrectly. I used the Spanish version: 'Revuloción' without the accented o to make my life a little easier." The thing that came to mind was wow, how Anglocentric, but then I remembered that it was more about the Culture of England than dealing with the language at large that's also spoken in Canada, Australia, New Zealand, the United States, etc.

So, is there a word that means English-Language centered/-centric? If there is, I would thank you very much for obliging me. Otherwise, I think I am afraid that I am indeed at a loss for words.

I know there is "Anglophone", but it only conveys someone that is an English speaker, not someone that thinks that the entire world should cater to those that speak the English language and speak English around them even if they are in a foreign land [Mind you, this is only a rather extreme example of it, but it does more or less convey the feeling of what I am attempting to have others understand in a written format].

Comment: Welcome to the site! You could use *Anglophonocentric* if you wanted to be 100 % clear, but I think *Anglocentric* works well enough in this context.

Comment: And if you want the noun it is 'Anglocentricity'.

Comment: you could create a neologism... "language-centric" meaning that a speaker tends to think their own way of speaking and writing is better than that of other speech communities. "Ethnocentric" covers some of this, but focuses more on customs than language per se.

Answer (score 2):

Anglocentric does work for it being an English-based bias. But, if you feel the the use of an "easier spelling" of the word is also a type of cultural/language laziness, it could be considered ethnocentric.